# How to bind data for shared fragment only once for all controllers and pages?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to show *category* list in all pages. I have this code for showing items in **nav.jsp**:

```
<c:forEach var="category" items="${categoryList}">
       <p><a href="showCategory?id=${category.id}">${category.title}</a></p>
</c:forEach>
```

I use this code in controller request mapping method to bind value to page:

```
model.addObject("categoryList", postCategoryList);
```

I have included **nav.jsp** to main .jsp file and it works properly, but I have many controllers and pages. How to bind  `categoryList` value only once, for all controllers and request methods?

Comment: how about set data via `session` or `application` scope?

Comment: @lucumt Would you please show me an example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HandlerInterceptor`.

```
public class CategoryListAddInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryDao categoryDao; //for example

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                           HttpServletResponse response,
                           Object handler,
                           ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

        modelAndView.getModel().put("categoryList", categoryDao.getPostCategoryList());
    }        
}
```

In config xml file, add:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/demo/**"/> <!-- can add exclude patterns if needed -->
        <bean class="package.name.CategoryListAddInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

**UPDATE:**

As you have been getting `NullPointerException` while calling `modelAndView.getModel()` you can do this to achieve the same thing:

```
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response,
                       Object handler,
                       ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    request.setAttribute("categoryList", categoryDao.getPostCategoryList());
}
```

Comment: I used your approach, but I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` on `modelAndView.getModel()` line.

Comment: @Majid I have updated the ans according to your issue. Plus it would be better if you could share your handler code so i could understand why your `modelAndView` is `null`